# Volume slider only change the Master volume, not PCM

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the way Ubuntu adjusts my volume mixer levels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels)

Pulseaudio's default volume slider doesn't work well with my audio card: when I change the volume (through the volume icon or the keys on my keyboard), for the first 50% the PCM volumes gets adjusted and for the next 50% the master one.

This change happens in big increments of ~20%. The changes to PCM barely affects the volume level, while the Master slides does.

This makes the volume slider rather unusable: it's either way too low, or too loud and I can't set it properly.

Is there a way, preferably through pulseaudio and not by rebinding my keys to use amixer (as suggested in another post here) to only change the master volume without ever touching PCM?

I know you can play around with the `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common` file to achieve that effect, but this does not seem to be the proper way to change this: the change will get reverted next time pulseaudio gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I found the following: [How do I change the way Ubuntu adjusts my volume mixer levels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels)

The solution mentioned there worked for me.