# AudioQuest Dragonfly inaudible unless pushed over 100% volume

Tags: sound, volume-control

So I've been struggling with this issue for a little while and I can't seem to figure it out. I am on a clean install of Ubuntu (meaning I haven't messed about with audio stuff yet), and I am facing the same issue with my Dragonfly USB DAC as I have with other distros. When the volume is below 100%, the sound coming into my headphones through the DAC is barely audible, even when close to 100%. However, if I push the volume over 100% it becomes *very* audible, too loud in fact.

Is there a known "fix" for this issue? I'm assuming there's some way to get around this since the audio does play through the DAC, the issue is just the large jump from soft to very loud when going over 100% volume. When not using the USB DAC, the audio is as expected. I can comfortably listen at around 30% volume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known fix for this issue, but it does not mention the Dragonfly specifically, so I had a really hard time finding it too.

Basically what you need to do is edit a line in the /etc/pulse/default.pa file.

From:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

To:

```
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

Then from the command line run:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

This should cause pulseaudio to stop and then restart, though I had to reboot my computer to get it work.

I should also mention with this fix, you will hear output on the Dragonfly but will not be able to adjust the volume, until you select it as your output device in under System Settings -> Sound.

Take a look at:

- [How do I change the way Ubuntu adjusts my volume mixer levels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels) (This is where my answer is from)
- http://www.head-fi.org/t/617241/audioquest-dragonfly-review-affordable-outstanding-tiny-dac-amp/795 (Second post on this page)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for sharing. I should mention the reboot wasn't necessary for me, in case anyone is wondering.