# AudioEngine D3 USB DAC - volume either 0% or 100% via volume keyboard keys, alsamixer works fine

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, volume-control, audio-jack

Like the title says, I have a USB AudioEngine D3 DAC and headphone amplifier with software volume control. I can control the volume fine via `alsamixer` in a terminal, but that is rather inconvenient. I would like to use the volume control keys on my keyboard as they are meant to be used, but they only set the volume to 0% or 100%. When I press the volume up key once, the volume jumps to 100%, and when I press the volume down key, it jumps to 0%.

Adjusting volume level via the "Settings -> Sound" GUI means I have 0% volume until I drag the volume bar all the way to the right (100%), at which point I get 100% volume.

`alsamixer` shows the volume at 0% or 100% (as expected, I suppose) when I adjust my sound via sound settings or volume control keys. Setting the volume level to something reasonable via `alsamixer` results in the "Settings -> Sound" GUI showing 100% volume on its slider bar.

How can I get volume control keys working properly? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: HI - Could you please edit/paste the output of this `pactl list short sinks` - It could be that a 'not volume capable' stage of the device is set as default output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the D3 today and had this exact same problem. Check out the top answer on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels). For me, these instructions worked:

> There are a few variables which control how PulseAudio controls the volume. You can either edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (you'll have to be root to do that) to change the behavior for all users, or copy that file to `~/.pulse/default.pa` and then edit that file, to change behavior for the current user only.
>
> Open the file mentioned above. Find the row saying `load-module
>     module-udev-detect` and change it to:
>
> `load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1`
>
> To try your changes, restart PulseAudio with the following command:
>
> `killall pulseaudio`
>
> PulseAudio will then autospawn (restart itself).

I had a block in the config file that looked like this:

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

Then I simply added `ignore_dB=1` to the end of each `load-module` line, so that the two lines looked like

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0 ignore_dB=1
...
load-module module-detect ignore_dB=1
```