# AudioEngine D3 USB DAC - volume slider and alsamixer volume don't map correctly

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

This question is related to [this one asked by willem.hill](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112658/audioengine-d3-usb-dac-volume-either-0-or-100-via-volume-keyboard-keys-alsa/1121228#1121228).

In a nut shell, the problem here is that volume slider in sound doesn't map correctly to alsamixer's volume for AudioEngine D3 USB DAC.
The entire volume range in alsamixer is only mapped to a very small portion on sound's volume slide.

slider at 0%
[image: slider at 0%]

slider at 100%
[image: slider at 100%]

Please see below for the output of `pactl list short sinks`.

```
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
10  alsa_output.usb-Audioengine_Audioengine_D3_Audioengine-00.iec958-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

Can this be fixed by editing `analog-output.conf.common`?

Thanks in advance.